# Subscribing Platform Events from Lighting Component in Mobile

Tags: mobile, platform-event

Has anybody succeeded in subscribing platform events from a LWC or Aura component from Mobile? It works in Desktop version but does not work as expected in Mobile App. I am using empAPI. I think in 2019 release it was mentioned that it support Mobile but in the latest version/edition there is no mention about mobile support. So I am wondering if there is any way to subscribe to the platform events from Mobile Lightning component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce does not support subscribing to events in a lightning component in mobile and there is no alternate to it either.

empAPI is not supported in Mobile devices.